# Compilation error in Node.getTextContent for jdk 6

Tags: java

java Source code not compiling with jdk 6.

```
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 Node node = list.item(0);
 String txtContent = node.getTextContent();
```

getTextContent() not found in the jdk 6

how can solve this compilation issue.

Comment: My guess is that you're importing the wrong `Node` type. It's impossible to say without seeing some more code though. Please produce a short but complete example.

Comment: I guess, you're coding with a "simple" editor. Switch over to an IDE like eclipse or netbeans - it will help solving those problems at editing time already.

Comment: @Andreas_D is that really worth switching to an IDE? You get the same messages, just a bit earlier. In my experience, IDEs are far more trouble than they're worth, especially if you have built up a lot of experience in a good text editor like vim.

Comment: @mgiuca - yes - because an IDE can tell you right away  *which* `Node` class you're actually using and *what* are the known methods. You'll see the red line in your code and the quick fix proposals greatly help to find the solution.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I came here with the same problem.  Even worse: I had two projects side by side, both targetting the same JRE (1.6), and one was able to resolve Node.getTextContent() while the other wasn't.  I resolved it sort of by accident; I went to project properties | Java Build Path | Order and Export tab, selected the JRE (which was at the bottom of the list) and clicked the "Top" button to move it to the top.  My problem went away.  It appears that the Node I wanted was hidden by another one.  :-\  Maybe this will help with your problem.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, but it doesn't suggest why the method is not resolving if none of my projects point to any JRE except 1.6

Comment: Moving the JRE on top of other dependencies also solved the problem for me ... weird

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your tip helped me to solve this problem. I spent about 30 min. on this issue :]

Comment: OMG, I moved the JRE on top of other dependecies and also solved the problem. Tks a lot!

Comment: My code compiled from the command line, but not in Eclipse.
So it was my problem and not the code/pom files.
So changing Order and Export worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Had the same behaviour for org.w3c.dom.Element and had to move JRE System Library above Maven Dependencies.

Comment: This might have taken me forever to figure out on my own.  Thanks!

Comment: Amazing!  Saved me god knows how much time! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Although a late post... maybe someone will find this useful.

I didn't like the manual project setting with JRE on top because all my colleagues would have to go trough this every time the project was imported, so I found another solution.

In my case I had the following dependency tree: org.reflections (0.9.8) -> dom4j (1.6.1) -> xml-apis (1.0.b2).

In order to fix it, I added an exclusion in the org.reflections dependency, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In your case maybe there is another dependency that imports a faulty jar. E.g.: [Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

Please check http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.w3c.dom.Node to see all the jars that contain that class.

Answer (score 8):

I have also faced the similar problem. It is nothing to do with the Source Code. Steps to solve the problem is,

1. Go to project Properties (Right click on project and choose properties)
2. Select Java Build Path
3. Go to Order and Export tab

[image: Order and Export setting in Buildpath]

4. Make sure your JRE library is on TOP. If it is not in top, make it to top.
5. Click on OK and see after completing the build progress in right down.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone working with hibernate the solution is similar to virussu_ro above.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a long shot, but are you sure you're using JDK 6? Sometimes IDEs like Eclipse have a dropdown in the Project window that lets you choose a version, and it may be set to 1.4. Or you may have your CLASSPATH set incorrectly. Worth checking if you have ever had Java 1.4 installed.

I ask because `Node.getTextContent` was added in JDK 1.5, so the only way I can explain its absence is that you are using the [Java 1.4 version of org.w3c.dom.Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

Comment: No way. He says, he's compiling with jdk6 - and, assuming this is true (double check and check again!!! Hint: `javac -version`), `Node#getTextContent()` really should be found.

Comment: @Andreas_D Indeed it should be found! That's why I'm skeptical that he's really running JDK 6. I mean, why else would that class exist but not have that method?

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code to determine location of jar:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    ProtectionDomain domain = org.w3c.dom.Node.class.getProtectionDomain();
    System.out.println("domain: " + domain);
    CodeSource codeSource = domain.getCodeSource();
    if(codeSource != null) {
       System.out.println("location: " + codeSource.getLocation());
    } else {
        System.out.println("null location, probably JRE class");
    }
```

Maybe there is a jar on classpath that contains org.w3c.dom.Node class and hides the correct one.