# XML Parser Class loading issues in Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, apache-karaf

I have an OSGi bundle that does some LDAP operations. It uses Apache Shared Directory to do these operations. I'm using Maven Bundle Plugin to build my bundle. For lack of time and resources, I have to go with  in pom.xml, which includes Apache Shared Directory and other jars it depends on, in the generated bundle. One of the dependencies is Xerces, followed by Xml apis. When I include these two jars in the bundle, Karaf throws a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
```

Further investigation revealed that the class `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` is being loaded from two jars - `Xml-apis.jar` that I included in my bundle and the JRE's `rt.jar`, which is causing the `ClassCastException`. Since this class is being loaded from `rt.jar`, I figured I don't need to include `Xml-apis.jar` in my bundle and removed it. However, now I see the `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory not found by mybundle.ldap [149]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:812)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:72)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1807)[org.apache.felix.framework-3.2.2.jar:]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)[:1.6.0_35]
```

So, if I include the `xml-apis.jar`, I get the `ClassCastException`. If I don't include it, I get the `ClassNotFoundException`. Is there a way I can resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Import the package `javax.xml.parsers`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I am importing javax.xml.parsers package.  `<Import-Package>
                            javax.net,
                            javax.net.ssl,
                            javax.xml.*,
         javax.api.*, 
       javax.xml.parsers,`. Doesn't seem to help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Have you looked at the generated manifest? Does it really import this package? If it does, then that would mean that he could resolve the package (you'd have gotten a different error otherwise), but that package didn't contain the class.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried commenting out the line

> javax.xml.parsers, \

in the etc/jre.properties file? This should prevent loading of the class from rt.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! (at least for me)

You can find a very good explanation of the problem in this link:
[Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

As you can read, actually, it's a problem of Xerces compatibility. Maybe you don't use Xerces, but probably you are using a library that use Xerces.

The solution in my case was to use an old version of xerces (lucene-xercesImpl) and exclude any reference to xml-apis o xerces:

```
<properties>
   <ver.jena>2.10.1</ver.jena>
   <ver.jena-sdb>1.3.6</ver.jena-sdb>
   <ver.h2>1.3.173</ver.h2>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
      <artifactId>jena-sdb</artifactId>
      <version>${ver.jena-sdb}</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
      <type>pom</type>
      <version>${ver.jena}</version>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
   </dependency>
```

Hope this help!