# Spring 4.0.3 xerces 2.9.1 and Thymeleaf on Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: spring, weblogic, xerces, thymeleaf

I am facing a wired issue during spring application context initialization. Based on the warning from thymeleaf( Please see this link : [[http://www.darkedges.com/blog/?cat=28][1]](http://www.darkedges.com/blog/?cat=28%5d%5b1%5d))

I have added weblogic-application.xml and weblogic.xml and until I use spring version 3.x there are no issues with xerces and xlan in pom dependencies. But as soon as I upgraded spring version to 4.0.3.RELEASE my deployment failed saying

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public java.util.Properties com.freddiemac.car.CarSpringConfiguration.sqlQueries()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:123)
    at java.util.XMLUtils.getLoadingDoc(XMLUtils.java:75)
    at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:57)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:852)
    at org.springframework.util.DefaultPropertiesPersister.loadFromXml(DefaultPropertiesPersister.java:78)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I switch back to spring 3.x everything is working fine.

I am using Spring MVC 4.0.3 with Thymeleaf 2.X and Weblogic 10.3.6 with the xerces and xlan from the above mentioned url.

Please help!

Comment: darkedge link is giving me a 404 when I try to visit it

Comment: Please see this : http://www.darkedges.com/blog/?cat=28

Answer (score 0):

First of all - Thymeleaf is at the moment primary designed for Spring 3, so I would recommend to use Spring 3, except you have special requirement which force you to use Spring 4.

Then you should try if it is a WebLogic specific problem or if it happens with Jetty or Tomcat too.

Then check the common information about maven and [xml-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992400/classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-jaxp-documentbuilderfactoryimpl-cannot-be)