# JasperReport cannot run on Jboss6.0 but woeks fine on tomcat 7

Tags: jboss, jsperf

I have created a JasperReport application and it works fine on tomcat server. But when I use the same jar to run on Jboss it shows the error

```
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_75]
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_75]
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:854) [:]
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778) [:]
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:127) [:6.1.0.Final]

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992400/classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-jaxp-documentbuilderfactoryimpl-cannot-be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Jboss contains the class **"org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl"** in Jboss lib and the same class **"javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"** contained in the lib folder of the application war file. So both the classes gets conflicted. That's why the class cast exception occurred.

To solve the issue, remove the jar file containing the class **"javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"** from the lib folder of the application war file. The class **"javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"** contained in the **xml-apis-1.3.02.jar** file.

So remove **xml-apis-1.3.02.jar** from the war file. It can be done by excluding it in the maven's **"pom.xml"** file