# Conflicts between JDK6 and xml-apis

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader, xerces, opensaml

After upgrading OpenSAML from 1.1 to 2.6.1, which needs xerces-impl dependency, the following stack appears on startup :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
       at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:131) ~[xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:1.6.0_45]
       at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:831) ~[glassfish.jaxb_1.0.0.0_2-1-12.jar:2.1.12]
       ... 68 common frames omitted
```

xerces-impl redefine some jre classes and comes with xml-apis which redefine some jre interfaces.
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl come from xerces-impl.

I'm on weblogic 10.3.5 and JDK 6.

I read [Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven) and try to exclude xml-apis but xerces-impl throws NoClassDefFoundError. Copying xml-apis and xerces-impl in jre/lib/endorsed throws ClassCastException too (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/).

Adding -Djavax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl on startup command throws :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:128) ~[xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:80) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
```

Then adding -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl throws :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:79)
```

I don't know what to do next. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to javax.xml.bind as prefer-application

```
<wls:package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</wls:package-name>
```

in weblogic.xml, adding jaxb dependencies solved my problem :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb-impl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic includes its own versions of a lot of these libraries on the classpath, & they can interfere with your app.  Try adding a section like this to the `weblogic.xml` file:

```
<weblogic-web-app>

  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.helpers.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.impl.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.spi.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
  </container-descriptor>
  ...
</weblogic-web-app>
```

The example shows the packages for slf4j; I'm not sure what they will be for xerces.  If you have access to the [wls-cat tool](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/using-new-weblogic-classloader-analysis.html), that should help figure it out.

---

Update

Classpath conflicts between WLS and your app may be fixed in one of three ways.

1. Add the package to the `<prefer-application-packages>` element so the app's take precedence
2. Change the POM to note that a particular dependency is `provided` by WLS
3. Exclude the dependency from the POM entirely.

I suggest using `mvn dependency:tree` with the former version of OpenSAML, note the dependencies. Then change to the new OpenSAML version, & note what new dependencies are pulled in. Take a look at the WLS server's `modules` directory to see what libraries WLS is using, cross-reference this with the changed dependencies with the new OpenSAML version, and decide which of the 3 possibilities seems to be the best fit. For example, if you can see that WLS uses an earlier version of a lib than your app does, you probably want to use option 1. Do this until you can get the app to deploy, then use wls-cat to finish the job.

Comment: I added : 
 <wls:prefer-application-packages>
  <wls:package-name>javax.xml.parsers.*</wls:package-name>
 </wls:prefer-application-packages>
but I still have the ClassCastException. As it fail starting, I don't see information about my app in the wls-cat. As SAXParserFactory comes from xml-apis, I don't understand how I can have a ClassCastException with xerces implementation in the 2 first StackTraces.

Comment: Did you also remove all of the extra -D parameters you added in earlier troubleshooting? My experience it none of that is necessary.  Note that the classpath exception mentions `org.apache.xerces`. This means you'll likely need at least `<package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</package-name>` in the weblogic.xml file. There may be others required.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With that package-name in weblogic-application.xml and no "-D" option in startCmd, I have a ClassCastException on a different class : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:79)
 ... 54 more

Comment: I added an update. Unfortunately I have no list of things to put in `<prefer-application-packages>` or POM changes that will make the problem go away, figuring it out is unique to each situation. I did find a [blog post](https://vasya10.wordpress.com/category/weblogic/) mentioning that xml-apis can be one source of an issue.