# How to get ${buildNumber} in TFS with Maven?

Tags: maven, tfs, azure-pipelines

I need to add the buildNumber in my generated manifest file with Maven. We use `TFS`(Team Foundation Server) as our repository. Is there any way to access it?

Below link explain the how get build number with Git, SVN or Mercuria.

http://www.yegor256.com/2014/07/03/how-to-read-manifest-mf.html

I also need the same thing with TFS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

Comment: The question is about buildnumber or changeset in tfs vc ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ${env.TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER} environment variable to get TFS build number.

Please have a check on this link: https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2014/12/16/Setting-a-build-version-in-a-JAR-file-from-TFS-build.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct variable number is env.TFS_CHANGESET or just TFS_CHANGESET. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Predefined variables in TFS:

- `Build.SourceVersion` - Git: The commit ID.
- `BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` - TFVC: the changeset.

A list of all variables here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables