# maven: Multiple annotations found at this line:

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a very simple maven project to run some `selenium` tests. Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>selenium</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

but it complains with:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Failure to transfer xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
     repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original 
     error: Could not transfer artifact xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): SOCKS : 
     authentication failed org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2 from 
     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
     update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2 
     from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): SOCKS : authentication failed at
```

**When i remove the dependencies it works fine**

What is wrong in pom.xml?

Comment: `Original 
     error: Could not transfer artifact xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2` something triggers this

Comment: find out which dependency triggers it and exclude the xalan from it would at least be 1 way

Comment: Try deleting target folder and force update(Follow steps given by Jimmy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem get resolved after the below steps:

1. Right click on project
2. Maven -> Update Maven Project
3. Tick the check boxes as below

[image]