# What's is relationship between xerces.jar, xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar. Is there conflict among these three jar?

Tags: java, jar

Recently encountered xerces.jar errors in my development process. 
When these three jar exist in webinf/libs at the same time, report java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

But if I remove xerces.jar from webinf/libs, servlet run with no problem.

So what's the relationship of xerces.jar , xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar.

Is there any conflict among these three jar? 
My jdk version is 1.6.

Thank you,

Comment: Please check [this][1] for detailed explanation


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven

Comment: thanks,finally got the reason...