# ERROR StatusLogger Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I have an application that used log4j1.2.17.Now I want to change it to log4j2.
So i changed the pom.xml (I'm sure that i have remove the log4j1 in any dependency), add the log4j2.xml. The log4j2 works fine, and it log the infomation that i want.But i got the below error at the begining.

```
ERROR StatusLogger Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities to false on DocumentBuilderFactory org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@476ac20c: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.disableDtdProcessing(XmlConfiguration.java:205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener.contextInitialized(Log4jServletContextListener.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR StatusLogger Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities to false on DocumentBuilderFactory org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@476ac20c: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.disableDtdProcessing(XmlConfiguration.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener.contextInitialized(Log4jServletContextListener.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR StatusLogger Caught java.lang.AbstractMethodError setting feature http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd to false on DocumentBuilderFactory org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@476ac20c: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.setFeature(XmlConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.disableDtdProcessing(XmlConfiguration.java:207)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.newDocumentBuilder(XmlConfiguration.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener.contextInitialized(Log4jServletContextListener.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ZKH/WebShop/target/esp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.9.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ZKH/WebShop/target/esp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

My jdk version is 1.8.0_102.
Maven version is 3.3.9.
log4j2 version is 2.9.1.

I view the issue of log4j. The [LOG4J2-2026](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2026) seems to fix it, but version of log4j2 that i used is already 2.9.1 . I don't know what cause this error.

Comment: I had a similar problem with log4j2 incurring java.lang.AbstractMethodError errors. The following stackoverflow post helped solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven  I removed all xerces and xml_apis mentions from my pom file, including adding xerces and xml_apis exclusion elements from third party dependencies (so that they would use the default versions that come with java api)

Answer (score 10):

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

For me it was resolved by excluding xercesImpl dependency:

```
implementation (group: 'com.github.mkolisnyk', name: 'cucumber-runner', version: 'X.X.X') {
            exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'
}
```

You can check your project dependencies tree by:

```
gradlew <project>: dependencies --configuration
```

[Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the dependency to the pom file did not work. However, it was resolved after adding the below 2 jars to my runtime lib folder

1. xercesImpl.jar
2. xml-resolver.jar