# xerces jar name changes behaviour

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I have an older application that uses a jar named xerces.jar. Looking at this I can see that it is the same as xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar from the maven repository.

When I run the application the xml validation behaves differently depending on if the jar is named xerces.jar or xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar.

I suspect there is something going on with the order that it it found on the classpath but I don't fully understand what is going on.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

The particular change is this:
The start tag looks like:

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.foo.com/messaging" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" release="006" version="010" xsi:schemaLocation="file:///C:/SOME/PATH">
```

When the jar is named "xerces.jar" this accepted when the app validates against a specific schema.   When the jar is named "xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar" then it gives the error: Attribute 'xsi:schemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element

Comment: Perhaps "xerces.jar" is not actually the same as "xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar"

Comment: Which behaviour is correct?

Comment: The jars are the same except for whitespace in some files.  Also, if I rename xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar the behaviour changes.

Comment: @user207421 - I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: Smells like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven