# How to exclude library from all dependencies in Kotlin DSL build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I started migration from `build.gradle` (Groovy) to `build.gradle.kts` (Kotlin DSL). The thing is that `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` (from `com.google.guava`) exists in several dependecies. Because of that build fails with `java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class ...` error.

Previously (when I had `build.gradle` in Groovy) this problem was solved with this snippet:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

But I can't find anything similar using Kotlin DSL.
Could you please provide Kotlin alternative for the snippet above or suggest any other solution on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might work (though I haven't tried it):

```
configurations.forEach { it.exclude("com.google.guava", "listenablefuture") }
```

Comment: Works great in my build.gradle.kts 

Comment: not works when the dependency coming from plugin

Answer (score 71):

This works with the Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude(group = "com.google.guava", module = "listenablefuture")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For two group you can use like this:

```
configurations.forEach {
            it.exclude("com.google.guava", "listenablefuture")
            it.exclude(group = "org.jetbrains", module = "annotations")
        }
```