# Weblogic classloader issue

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader

I have a problem with Weblogic classloader.

When I try to deploy my app on WL 12.2.1.2.0 it fails. 
In the logs on my server I see

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal`

The class belongs to `xml-apis` library. The library comes into my app with another dependency(so as transitive dependency). The version of `xml-apis` is 1.4.01.

After that I added exception in my deployment descriptor:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.w3c.dom.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

And later a new deployment. The described issue with `org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal` was solved. There is no any information about missing `org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal` class anymore.

But there is a new issue:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.Document`

After analysis I figured out that `org.w3c.dom.Document` class comes from JRE(jre/lib/rt.jar).
So in deployment descriptor I've said:

"if I need something from `org.w3c.dom.*` package - please load it from my app distribution". And now there is such inconsistency.

I've had idea to use WL Classloader Analysis Tool(CAT) but it is impossible because the deploy was failed.

Excluding `xml-apis` and `xerces` libraries from my ear we mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840656/7841898) didn't help me.

Does anybody have idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding `xercexImpl` library from my EAR without changing the deployment descriptor was solved my problem. Mentioned classes during new deployment were loaded from WL distribution.